# Updating UI from handler

Tags: android, android-handler

I'm using handler for communication with my other thread which is responsible for bluetooth communication. When the communication is established I want to send list of arrays of bytes and show the progress.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
                        @Override
                        public void handleMessage(Message inputMessage) {
                            switch (inputMessage.what) {
                                case CONNECTION_STATE:
                                    connected = (boolean) inputMessage.obj;
                                    Log.d(TAG, "connected= " + String.valueOf(connected));
                                    if (connected) {
                                        for (int i = 0; i < data2send.size(); i++) {
                                            if (!isCancelled) {
                                                isPrinting = true;
                                                printButton.setText(getString(R.string.cancel));
                                                byte[] bytes2send = new byte[data2send.get(i).getDataLength()];
                                                System.arraycopy(data2send.get(i).getData(), 0, bytes2send, 0, data2send.get(i).getDataLength());
                                                try {
                                                    int progress = (i+1) * 100 / data2send.size();
                                                    Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: progress = " + progress + " %");
                                                    String statusString = getString(R.string.sending_page) + String.valueOf(i+1) + getString(R.string.of) + String.valueOf(data2send.size());
                                                    Log.d(TAG, statusString);
                                                    status.setText(statusString);
                                                    progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                                                    connectThread.write(bytes2send);
                                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                                    Log.e(TAG, "connection error");
                                                }
                                            } else {
                                                isPrinting = false;
                                                printButton.setText(getString(R.string.print_caps));
                                                break;
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    connectThread = new ConnectThread(printer, handler);
                    connectThread.start();
                }
```

Neither TextView content nor ProgressBar cannot be updated when the data is being sent, but logging works (log.d).

Comment: As the `Handler` process is asynchronous, you have to send all your UI updates to the UI thread (the main thread). To do so, you can use the `runOnUiThread()` method, from `Activity` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Activity` make a new `void`

```
private void updateUI(final String statusString, final int progress) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            status.setText(statusString);
            progressBar.setProgress(progress);            
        }
    });

}
```

Then, inside your handler

```
 try {
     int progress = (i+1) * 100 / data2send.size();
     Log.d(TAG, "onProgressUpdate: progress = " + progress + " %");
     String statusString = getString(R.string.sending_page) + String.valueOf(i+1) + getString(R.string.of) + String.valueOf(data2send.size());
     Log.d(TAG, statusString);
     updateUI(statusString, progress);
    ...
    ...
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. UpdateUI is called instantly, but UI is updated only after sending all data is finished.